# Upload Img using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I would like to upload image using ajax jquery
this is my view :

```
<form id="checkout-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="input-file" type="file" name="identity_id" id="identity_id">
</form>
```

and  my jquery :

```
    <script>
    $('#checkout-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $i = $( '#identity_id' ),
    input = $i[0].files[0];
    $.ajax({
       url:"{{ route('user.order.create') }}",
       method:"POST",
       data:{
            identity_id:input
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: false,
       cache: false,
       success:function(){

       }
     })
    })
   });
  </script>
```

and showing error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on
> 'Blob': Illegal invocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
        $('#checkout-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var i = $( '#identity_id' ),
        var formData = new FormData();
        var input = i[0].files[0];
        formData.append('identity_id',input);
        $.ajax({
           url:"{{ route('user.order.create') }}",
           method:"POST",
           data:formData,
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           success:function(){
    
           }
         })
        })
       });
      </script>
```

Comment: is it possible send like this = data:{ identity_id:input } ?

Comment: No, File upload only possible with FormData()